# How to plot contents of a UITextField in a graph Xcode

Tags: xcode, graph

I need to take the contents of a UITextField and insert them into an on screen graph. Can someone please tell me the best way to do this? I was thinking of using CorePlot. Thanks!

Comment: Core Plot is the way to go.  Their website has some great resources, and sample code.  And the people behind the company are very helpful.

Comment: Yes, but can you tell me how to implement this in my project?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TextField, I would place it's contents into an array. Core Plot's graphs are all generated from arrays.  So you would need to get the text, put it into an array, and then graph the array.  If you look on their website they have a couple of examples like the CPTTestApp for which ever OS you are using and the DropPlot and the Rangeplot all have great examples.  Hope this helps.